# How to apply the UV map of a scan to a retopologized model?

Tags: uv

Using photogrammetry, I obtained a perfectly textured model. I created a retopologized low density mesh of it. Now, I'd like to apply the UV map of the original scan to the new mesh. What is the best option to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to tranfer the uv map since there is a difference in face count between the two meshes.
what i would do is unwrap the low poly mesh and bake the diffuse from the high poly.
use selected to active option when baking and enough samples, the result is an approximation but can be a good start for re-texturing.

Comment: Data transfer can be used to bake UV map in this situation

Comment: Are you sure that data transfer can be used when the poly count isn't the same ?